# VBA Excel- Copying Rows based on two columns having matching data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running into an issue doing reconciliation where some of my assets children do not match parents usage status, ownership, etc. I need to pull all parents to a new sheet, to manually verify all data is correct. This is the first part of my problem.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiOu1.png)

Example shown above.

In row 4997, the two EQ numbers match. This is the parent row. I need to copy all rows that having matching EQ numbers in columns B and C into a separate worksheet. I will then edit them manually, so that all other columns are accurate to our actual books.

That is my first problem.

Beyond this, a separate problem.

I need to then take all info that has been changed in separate worksheet and replace old parent information in original worksheet with new parent information.
From there, I need to make all children reflect the same information. As you can see in the example, the parent on row 4997 reads as rented, yet all children underneath it read as available.
I need columns E, F, G, H, I, and J, of all children, to reflect the same information from those columns as the parent.

All children reflect the same EQ number as the parent in column C. EQ0005212.

This is a large list, 1000+ parents.

I've found something similar to what I want to do, but it doesn't fit what I need exactly.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLstRow As Long
Dim keywords() As String
Dim maxKeywords, i, j, k As Integer


maxKeywords = 6
ReDim keywords(1 To maxKeywords)

keywords(1) = "_LC"
keywords(2) = "_LR"
keywords(3) = "_LF"
keywords(4) = "_W"
keywords(5) = "_R"
keywords(6) = "_RW"

lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For j = 1 To lngLstRow
  For i = 1 To maxKeywords
    If keywords(i) = Right(Sheets("Results").Range("L" & j).Value,     
Len(keywords(i))) Or _
      keywords(i) = Right(Sheets("Results").Range("M" & j).Value, 
Len(keywords(i))) Then
        k = k + 1
          Rows(j & ":" & j).Copy
            Sheets("sheet1").Select
              Range("A" & k).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
  Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

Any help in just solving the first problem would be greatly appreciated, but if you can figure out a solution to the second, I'd be forever in your debt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i've got your first problem solved, I wont be able to solve the second till tomorrow, if nobody does by then, I have an idea for that. **EDIT: see edit below, I promised I would be back :)**

```
Sub findParent()
    Dim masterWs As New Worksheet
    Dim masterEndRc As Long
    Set masterWs = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim parentWs As New Worksheet
    Set parentWs = Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim masterCounter As Long
    Dim parentCounter As Long
    parentCounter = 1
    masterCounter = 1
    Dim colBStr As String 'set up temp variables, you could compare values directly
    Dim colCstr As String 'but call me crazy, i think that this way is more accurate

    masterEndRc = masterWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Do
        colBStr = masterWs.Cells(masterCounter, "B").Value 'Load the value into the temp variables
        colCstr = masterWs.Cells(masterCounter, "C").Value

        If colBStr = colCstr Then
            masterWs.Cells(masterCounter, "B").EntireRow.Cut parentWs.Cells(parentCounter, "A")
            parentWs.Cells(parentCounter, "E").Value = masterCounter 'Make this the first empty column, this is so that we can find its original row
            'for reinsert later
            parentCounter = parentCounter + 1
        End If
        masterCounter = masterCounter + 1
    Loop While masterCounter <= masterEndRc
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Ok second problem solved :) make sure to change any of the variables to match your sheet, like columns and sheet names. Run the first sub under macros above and then run the second sub below.

```
Sub restoreParent()
    Dim masterWs As New Worksheet
    Dim masterEndRc As Long
    Set masterWs = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim parentWs As New Worksheet
    Set parentWs = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim parentEndRc As Long
    Dim parentCounter As Long
    Dim oldRowLong As Long
    Dim rowColl As New Collection 'for storing of the parent row numbers for use while changing child rows later
    parentEndRc = parentWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    parentCounter = 1

    Do
        oldRowLong = parentWs.Cells(parentCounter, "E").Value
        rowColl.Add oldRowLong
        parentWs.Cells(parentCounter, "B").EntireRow.Cut masterWs.Cells(oldRowLong, "A")
        parentCounter = parentCounter + 1
    Loop While parentCounter <= parentEndRc

    changeChildRows rowColl, masterWs
End Sub

Function changeChildRows(rowColl As Collection, masterWs As Worksheet)
    Dim nextChildRow As Long
    Dim childRowCounter As Long
    Dim parentRow As Variant
    Dim firstChild As Boolean
    firstChild = True

    For Each parentRow In rowColl
        childRowCounter = parentRow
        Do
            If firstChild = True Then
                nextChildRow = parentRow + 1
                If masterWs.Cells(parentRow, "C").Value = masterWs.Cells(nextChildRow, "C") Then
                    masterWs.Cells(nextChildRow, "D").Value = masterWs.Cells(parentRow, "D").Value 'Make sure to change these column values to match yours
                End If
                firstChild = False
            ElseIf firstChild = False Then
                nextChildRow = nextChildRow + 1
                If masterWs.Cells(parentRow, "C").Value = masterWs.Cells(nextChildRow, "C") Then
                    masterWs.Cells(nextChildRow, "D").Value = masterWs.Cells(parentRow, "D").Value 'Make sure to change these column values to match yours
                End If
            End If
        childRowCounter = childRowCounter + 1
        Loop Until masterWs.Cells(childRowCounter, "C").Value <> masterWs.Cells(parentRow, "C").Value
        firstChild = True
    Next parentRow
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not repeating this I would suggest doing this wihout VBA.

Just add a column with a formula: =IF(B1 = C1;1;0) (drag it) or even simpler =B1=C1. If they match you are going to have 1 (else 0) and then you can filter all the parents and copy to a new sheet/file.

After editing parents, in your table in columns E, F, G, H, I, and J just put INDEX MATCH formulas (or worse VLookup) (drag them of course). You should be comparing the C column with the parents' numbers in that edited table (you can choose B or C as they are the same if you are using INDEX MATCH, VLookup is not that convenient). There are lots of nice tutorials how to use these functions.

If you really want vba, you could basically record this and modify a bit.